# BT 4.0 LE consumer profile with iOS

Tags: ios, profile, core-bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy, spp

iPhone 4S [BT 4.0 LE custom profile SPP] <---> H/W Device[BT 2.0, 3.0 SPP profile]

android [BT 2.0 or 3.0 profile SPP]      <---> H/W Device[BT 2.0, 3.0 SPP profile]

is it possible? communication with Consumer profile based SPP(BT 4.0 LE) profile and SPP profile(BT 3.0 or 2.0)

if possible i want to docs(or source code) about make SPP profile using CoreBluetooth framework.

Answer (score 1):

Serial Port Profile (SPP) uses RFCOMM is not a Low Energy (LE) profile. So even with BT 4.0 hardware that supports LE you are using the classic Bluetooth of the spec. CoreBluetooth is an LE API, it cannot control SPP.

The compatibility of the Bluetooth profiles are based on the major version number. For instance, profile X 1.0 is not expected to be compatible/interoperable with profile X 2.0, but profile X 1.1 is expected to be compatible/interoperable with profile X 1.5.

The interoperability is defined per profile. I think the latest SPP is 1.1, So as long as you are using SPP 1.X with each other the above should work.